# Error while using Window Clause in Oracle Query

Tags: oracle, window, analytical

I have been looking at this code for the past two days now and I can not seem to get it to work.
It does work without the Window clause though.

It keeps giving me:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.
```

```sql
select P.*,
       first_value(product_name) over (w) MAX_PRICE,
       Last_value(product_name) over (w) MIN_PRICE
from   product P
       window w as (
         partition by product_category
         order by price desc
         range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
       );
```

Comment: What is the version of your DBMS? It works in 21c, but with no parentheses around window name: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b45664d6819794aa9bca2fea6022699f

Comment: The version I am currently using is 19C. I guess that explains the error. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window clause goes inside the analytic function:

```
select P.*,
       first_value(product_name) over (
         partition by product_category
         order by price desc
         range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
       ) AS MAX_PRICE,
       Last_value(product_name) over (
         partition by product_category
         order by price desc
         range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
       ) MIN_PRICE
from   product p;
```

Or, from Oracle 21, you can use:

```sql
select P.*,
       first_value(product_name) over w AS MAX_PRICE,
       Last_value(product_name)  over w AS MIN_PRICE
from   product p
       window w as (
         partition by product_category
         order by price desc
         range between unbounded preceding and unbounded following
       )
```

*(Without the brackets around the window in the analytic function.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e93e4f8c0fe96982830a3dca810a248d)*

Comment: Oracle 21c introduced this handy ANSI standardized feature: see [New features: Enhanced Analytic Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Changes-in-This-Release-for-Oracle-Database-SQL-Language-Reference.html#GUID-3C11D3A9-8B14-4DCC-B212-B7FE57EE81E8), new [Analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056) syntax and [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b45664d6819794aa9bca2fea6022699f). Thanks God now we may retype less code)